# VB.NET Get dates for following week

Tags: .net, vb.net, date, dayofweek

I have used the following code to determine the dates for each day of the following week :

```
    Dim someDate As DateTime = Date.Today 

    Dim nextMonday As DateTime = someDate
    While nextMonday.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Monday
        nextMonday = nextMonday.AddDays(1)
    End While

    Dim nextTuesday As DateTime = someDate
    While nextTuesday.DayOfWeek <> DayOfWeek.Tuesday
        nextTuesday = nextTuesday.AddDays(1)
    End While
```

It works great, except for the future day that is the same as the current day. Eg. today is Friday 8/1/2016 and the code returns also 8/1/2016, where it should in fact return 15/1/2016. All the dates for the other days are correct. 
Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: You could add 1 day to Today to let your cycles start on the next day (of course this means that search for monday on 11/1/2016 returns 18/1/2016. Is that acceptable?

Comment: Thank you Steve.That works for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could use following extension method:

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
Public Function StartOfWeek(dt As DateTime, firstDayOfWeek As DayOfWeek) As DateTime
    Dim diff As Int32 = dt.DayOfWeek - firstDayOfWeek
    If diff < 0 Then
        diff += 7
    End If

    Return dt.AddDays(-1 * diff).Date
End Function
```

If you want the complete next week in a `List(Of Date)`:

```
Dim startOfNextWeek As Date = Date.Today.AddDays(7).StartOfWeek(DayOfWeek.Monday)
Dim nextWeek = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(Function(d) startOfNextWeek.AddDays(d)).ToList()
```

The same without LINQ:

```
Dim nextWeek As New List(Of Date)
For d As Int32 = 0 To 6
    nextWeek.Add(startOfNextWeek.AddDays(d))
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be much better to use a function that looping through values. Something like this should do what you want:

```
Public Function FindNextDayOfWeek(startDate As Date, dayToFind As DayOfWeek) As Date
    Dim adjustment = 6 + (dayToFind - startDate.DayOfWeek)
    If adjustment > 7 Then adjustment -= 7
    Return startDate.AddDays(adjustment)
End Function
```

Tests:

```
FindNextDayOfWeek(#2015-01-13#, DayOfWeek.Tuesday) 'returns 19/01/2015
FindNextDayOfWeek(#2015-01-11#, DayOfWeek.Wednesday) ' returns 13/01/2015
FindNextDayOfWeek(#2015-01-11#, DayOfWeek.Monday) 'returns 18/01/2015
```

Comment: This doesn't work if `dayToFind` is *after* the `startDate.DayOfWeek`

Comment: Also, you have magic numbers.  You should make them constants

Comment: Hmm well yes but they pertain to the numbers of days in the week which is unlikely to change any time soon.

Comment: Sure, but that's not the only reason to make constants.  It's also to make it plainly clear what they mean.

Comment: Plus, it's [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don't_repeat_yourself)-er.  I know it's unlikely, but if you messed around with one of the 7s, you'd have to remember to change the other 7.

Answer (score 0):

This method should work for you:

```
Private Function GetNextDayOfWeek(afterDate As Date, targetDayOfWeek As DayOfWeek) As DateTime
    Const TotalDaysInWeek = DayOfWeek.Saturday - DayOfWeek.Sunday + 1 '+1 to account for zero indexed.
    Dim daysToAdd As Integer

    Select Case targetDayOfWeek
        Case Is < afterDate.DayOfWeek
            daysToAdd = afterDate.DayOfWeek - targetDayOfWeek - 1
        Case Is = afterDate.DayOfWeek
            daysToAdd = TotalDaysInWeek 'need to find exactly one week from "afterDate"
        Case Is > afterDate.DayOfWeek
            daysToAdd = targetDayOfWeek - afterDate.DayOfWeek
    End Select

    Return afterDate.AddDays(daysToAdd)
End Function
```